# Encrypted /home but does not ask for password

Tags: password, encryption, 21.04

I have installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my laptop and **after installation** I have encrypted my /home partition as described in this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/

Now, what happens is that after I boot my Ubuntu it automatically logs me in as my user but without any of my data, apps, etc. It also shows the initial welcoming screen that you get after a fresh installation where you can add accounts, choose if you want to send data do Canonical, etc.
Then, if I want to access all my data, I have to Log Out and Log In again. After that, all of my data and apps are visible. This happens every time after boot after I have encrypted my /home partition.

Is there a possibility to get Ubuntu to ask for my encryption password to decrypt my /home partition automatically without the need to Log Out and Log In again?

Thank you

Comment: The best way to do what you're asking is actually to use full disk encryption during installation.  It's also more secure, since encrypting only `/home` offers a false sense of security when files are frequently cached and mirrored in swap and other locations that are not under the user's home folder.  With full disk encryption, you enter a password during boot.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by changing your account to *not* sign in automatically. Here's how:

1. Open the Settings application:
   [image: Settings]
2. Click on Users, then "Unlock":
   [image: Users Settings]
   <sub>*Be sure to enter your password when prompted*</sub>
3. Change "Automatic Login" to disabled
4. There is no Step 4